# Haskell download on Mac not working

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc, haskell-platform

So, I'm tying to install Haskell onto my Macbook, but nothing is working. I've downloaded the 64bit full from Haskell.org, opened it up and gone through the installation process, it tells me it's completed and opens up an html page with more info, then nothing. The files should have been installed under my Library folder, but they're not there. It seems like nothing was installed. I've tried the core version as well, same problem.

I need this for a course, and it's become extremely tiresome not being able to use my laptop for the work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about just [installing the Stack build tool](https://haskell-lang.org/get-started/osx) via `curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh`? That page has some tutorials to get started using it.

Comment: So `which ghc` turns up nothing?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, if the html file opens, that means that something *was* installed.

In particular, the file that opens will have a url like:

`file:///Library/Haskell/ghc-8.2.1-x86_64/doc/start.html`

That url itself contains the directory in which things were installed.